# Notation in book homological algebra

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, additive-categories

In A Course in Homological Algebra,  Hilton and Stammbach.

Can anyone please explain me this notation $\{\varphi, \psi\}$ in the theorem:

Proposition 9.3: Given

$$A\xrightarrow{\{\varphi, \psi\}} B\oplus C\xrightarrow{ \left<{\gamma, \delta}\right>} D$$
we have 
            $\left<{\gamma, \delta}\right>\{\varphi, \psi\}=\gamma\varphi+\delta\psi$.

Similarly in the  Proposition 9.1.

I Don't find the notation in the book.

Thanks you all.

Comment: I think it's simply the map $a\mapsto (\varphi(a), \psi(a))$

Answer (score 3):

The map $\{ \varphi, \psi \}$ should be defined similarly to $\langle \gamma, \delta \rangle$ which is defined in the proof of Proposition 9.1.
Let $i_1 \colon B \to B \oplus C$ and $i_2 \colon C \to B \oplus C$ be the natural injections. For $\varphi \colon A \to B$ and $\psi \colon A \to C$ the map $\{ \varphi, \psi \} \colon A \to B \oplus C$ is defined by 
$$\{ \varphi, \psi \} = i_1 \varphi + i_2 \psi.$$

Comment: ------Thanks---

Answer (score 3):

In an abelian category $\oplus $ is the biproduct, that is $A\oplus B=A\times B$.
If $\varphi:A\to B $ and $\psi :A\to C $ are two morphisms then there is a unique morphism $\delta :A\to B\times C=B\oplus C$ st $p\circ \delta=\varphi $ and $q\circ \delta=\psi$ , where $p $ and  $q $ are the first and the second projection. Now $\{\varphi,\psi\} $ is $\delta $.

Comment: ------Thanks--- –